# Specify Location of Docker Images, Containers & Volumes for each docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, devops, virtualization

On a Ubuntu 18.04.3 machine with a new drive attached and mounted at `/mnt/elk`, is it possible to configure a `docker-compose.yml` such that all image, containers and volumes related to this `docker-compose.yml` will be stored in `/mnt/elk`?

Currently everything appears to be stored on the first drive at`/var/lib/docker/overlay`, `/var/lib/docker/containers` and `/var/lib/docker/volumes` and this drive is almost full. So we want to move a docker-compose setup (file shown below) from the first drive to the new drive at `/mnt/elk`.

The other docker-compose setups can remain on the first drive. It is ok to have the same image stored on both drives if another docker-compose.yml on the first drive requires that same image.

Thank you!

---

**`docker-compose.yml` for use in `/mnt/elk`**

From https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: elasticsearch
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: changeme
      # Use single node discovery in order to disable production mode and avoid bootstrap checks
      # see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html
      discovery.type: single-node
    networks:
      - elk

  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/pipeline
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "9600:9600"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    build:
      context: kibana/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./kibana/config/kibana.yml
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

Answer (score 1):

See global docker daemon configuration of `data-root` (only one data root can be configured):

> --data-root string                      Root directory of persistent Docker state (default "/var/lib/docker")

Stop docker daemon, [configure docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/) properly, e.g. `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
  "data-root": "/mnt/elk"
}
```

Copy data from `/var/lib/docker` to `/mnt/elk` and try to start docker daemon. You may have a problems with storage drivers (you may need to format new FS with proper parameters or may need to specify used storage driver explicitly). Note: just `copy`, because you want to have backup if something is going wrong. You may loose all volumes, images, containers, ..., so backup is highly recommended.